# .Net Linq - How to include children when parent is nullable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
.Include(x => x.Parents.Select(y => y.Children))
```

I'm fetching the GrandParent, but need to include the List of Parents, and if Parent is not null, include the List of its Children as well. Getting a compile error that the Parent is nullable. Which makes sense, but how to add a conditional Include for this?

Fairly simple use case but there's a surprising lack of documentation on this.

Comment: I should elaborate - this does build but fails at runtime. IDE does warn me about the line, and it does in fact fail on this line (not really a compile error I guess). Any ideas?

Comment: *How* does it fail? You should give more information, at least EF version and the exact exception message, maybe a class model + mapping code.

Comment: Ar you using Entity Framework old or Entity Framework Core? Matters a lot!

Comment: Seems like the issue is with the parent being nullable and the existing EF relation configs not being in sync. Will post a workaround for this

Comment: Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#navigating-and-including-nullable-relationships) for EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

```
_dbContext.GrandParents
    .Include(x => x.Parents)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Children)
```

`ThenInclude` takes Parent as root and then using expression related item(s) can be included. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: Without an explanation of why this works this answer is no better than a comment.

Comment: Code by it self is self explanatory: you `include` something and `then include` something that is deeped

Comment: This only works when the Parent is not nullable. I found a workaround for this:

.Include(x => x.Parents!)

But it seems like this is due to already existing ef configurations

Comment: So is it Parent or Parents inside of GrandParent? You should privide your configuration if it is unique

Comment: Also: _"Code by itself is self-explanatory"_ no, that's not according to the [Stack Overflow Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar issue, seems like this was due to EF relation configs not being properly set up and the nullability of the Parent.

Solution is similar to Kilas', just be sure to include the "!"

```
.Include(x => x.Parents!)
.ThenInclude(y => y.Children)
```

Comment: Not sure if a collection should be nullable as dbContext returns empty list rather than null (if it is included) if no values found. Would suggest initializing collection with empty collection.